# Metropolis Hastings algorithm without enough data

Tags: metropolis-hastings

In a metropolis hastings algorithm if i have not data or enough data, this will give me the prior means? I am asking this because I have made an algorithm and when i use just a few data this is not returning me a closer value for the parameters to the priors, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: This is just a matter of not having enough data, and have nothing to do with metropolis or any other algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

When one has no data, the posterior *is* the prior. But even with little data, the posterior *is no longer* the prior. This means that depending on the respective amounts of information in the prior and in the likelihood/data, the posterior may widely differ from the prior. The only clear check is to run the algorithm without the data.